# get the data from mongodb and insert in mongodb

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I am totally new to `mongoDB` . Currently , I am working on an application , where there is a search button which will search into the mongoDB, if value is present then it will return a JSON data .If not then I am giving a functionality through which user can add in mongoDB .

```
BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject();
whereQuery.put(URL_KEY, companyUrl);
NoticePay noticePay;
Document mongoDoc = collection.find(whereQuery).projection(fields(include(URL_KEY, NOTICE_PERIOD_KEY, PAY_SCALE_KEY), excludeId())).first();
```

Here , My query is not working properly .

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5804926140fbe41a7c5afbf0"), "companies" : { "companyName" : "ABC", "url" : "abc.com", "noticePeriod" : 50, "payScale" : "M" } }
```

So , How can I change my query so that I will be able to search it using this json .
Previously , It was working with following form of json

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5801dcf110227b0bcd178292"), "companyName" : "ABC ", "url" : "Abc.com", "noticekPeriod" : 60, "payScale" : "L" }
```

Can any one help me to solve this issue ? And also how can I insert a document in the 2nd form in mongodb using java ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you fill URL_KEY?

Comment: URL-KEY is just any string like "ABc"

Comment: where query should be like this collection.find( { "companies.url": "Abc.com" }).  whereQuery.put("companies.url", companyUrl);

Comment: If I want to add in mongoDB , Which will be in the 2nd format which i have mentioed in the question then how can I do that ?

Comment: this solution is Not working for me

Comment: It should work! add also URL_KEY="companies.url", NOTICE_PERIOD_KEY="companies.noticePeriod" and PAY_SCALE_KEY="companies. payScale"

Comment: Hi , It's working , But after that it is giving me null values. I am getting document like this  Document{{companies=Document{{url=ganesh, noticePeriod=50, payScale=L}}}}

Comment: Because there is no documents inserted with this structure

Comment: if (mongoDoc != null) {
            System.out.println("in if");
            System.out.println(mongoDoc.get(NOTICE_PERIOD_KEY));
            int noticePeriod = mongoDoc.getInteger("companies.noticePeriod");
            String payScale = mongoDoc.getString(PAY_SCALE_KEY);
            noticePay = new NoticePay(companyUrl, noticePeriod, payScale);
        } else {

Comment: { "_id" : ObjectId("5804a92040fbe41a7c5afc10"), "companies" : { "companyName" : "SBD", "url" : "aw", "noticePeriod" : 34, "payScale" : "H" } }  I have inserted the document in this way

Comment: you want to say that mongoDoc is null?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I change my query so that I will be able to search it using
>   this json { "_id" : ObjectId("5804926140fbe41a7c5afbf0"), "companies"
>   : { "companyName" : "ABC", "url" : "abc.com", "noticePeriod" : 50,
>   "payScale" : "M" } }

```
String URL_KEY = "companies.url";
String NOTICE_PERIOD_KEY = "companies.noticePeriod";
String PAY_SCALE_KEY = "companies.payScale";
BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject();
whereQuery.put(URL_KEY, companyUrl);
NoticePay noticePay;
Document mongoDoc = collection.find(whereQuery).projection(fields(include(URL_KEY, NOTICE_PERIOD_KEY, PAY_SCALE_KEY), excludeId())).first();
```

> how can I insert a document in the 2nd form in mongodb using java ?

```
String URL_KEY = "companies.url";
String NOTICE_PERIOD_KEY = "companies.noticePeriod";
String PAY_SCALE_KEY = "companies.payScale";
BasicDBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject();
dbObject.put("companies.companyName", companyName);
dbObject.put(URL_KEY, companyUrl);
dbObject.put(NOTICE_PERIOD_KEY, noticePeriod);
dbObject.put(PAY_SCALE_KEY, payScale);
collection.insert(dbObject);
```

Comment: I did the same thing .

Comment: I also added the document in that form as i have mentioed it in the comment

Comment: When I do System.out.println(mongoDoc.get(NOTICE_PERIOD_KEY));

Comment: Here it gives null value. can you explain me wh

Comment: You can not chain a property name like you're doing. Try with this System.out.println(mongoDoc.get("companies").get("noticePeri‌​od"));